# How to implement observer pattern for a swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, observer-pattern

I have a manager class which modifies the state of a member `Dictionary<Id, MyObject>` variable.

Is it possible to hand over a reference to this `Dictionary` and set up observers for all changes? I would like to avoid manually implementing an observer pattern, i.e. methods for registering listeners and trigger notifications manually.

Comment: I don't see of any way to do it besides making a wrapper object that wraps a dictionary and an RxSwift PublishSubject (or other observable source), making forwarding methods that have the hooks necessary for signalling changes to observers. But I would caution this, it's realllllly easy to make these things explode, performance wise. What's your use case?

Comment: I have a class which manages the model (from net, collecting sensor data, etc), and I'd like to display it in an IOS app's `UITableView`.

Comment: What is the dictionary for? It seems like an unnecessary "middle man". You can make your data sources (internet apis, sensors, etc.) observables, and subscribe your UI to them directly. There doesn't seem to be a need (from the limited context I have) to store any data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RxSwift and how easy is to manage obversables, but I think exactly because of the variety of source types it would be a mess to manage the sources / observables on the UI directly. On top of that I have a command line tool which uses the same manager class (with no UI.)

Comment: I also want to persist this model later locally and/or remotely... so I'd like to have the model class (currently the Dictionary) as a single unit.

Comment: " it would be a mess to manage the sources / observables on the UI directly." indeed, which is why that logic doesn't belong in the UI ("view") layer, but rather in the controller layer. In a reactive programming architecture, that's the main roll of the controller. It wires the UI to subscribe to the observables (the model), and occasionally the reverse (for when the UI updates the model). "On top of that I have a command line tool which uses the same manager class (with no UI.)" That just sounds like it needs a different view layer, which is just a different set of subscription behaviours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192337/discussion-between-alexander-and-tamas).

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggest you flip the direction of your approach. You're thinking that you such have a model (e.g. a dictionary) that's an authoritative source, which is updated in-place, which will then in turn inform subscribed observers of the change.

Instead, I suggest you flip it: you have a set of observables (your internet APIs, sensors, etc.) which are your raw data source. These can be subscribed to by your "data manager class", whose job it is to validate and filter the data. That object is itself an observable, and it's the authoritative data source for your model. Data is signalled directly to subscribed observers (without a middle man). If you need to persist that data, then the persistence system is just one of the possible subscribers, among multiple possible others (GUI, CLI, integration test, etc.)